# Converting Flash videos to an iPad readble format?

Tags: flash, ipad, video

I'm about to launch a site that creates user content using the Flash webcam recording functionality.  My problem is that iPad users can't watch the videos.  How could I create some add-on functionality for iPad users so that they are able to view the videos?

Answer (score 0):

Have the page displaying the video check the browser agent, and if it's an iPad/iPhone, either change the page's content or bounce the user to a page with the video embedded in a compatible format, such as HTML5. This requires storing the video in both formats on your server (doing conversions during off-peak hours), or doing on-demand conversions (at upload or viewing time). The former means that iPad users won't be able to immediately watch uploaded videos, and your server will have a significantly larger storage requirement to support a potentially small slice of users. The latter is potentially expensive, in terms of both time and server resources, meaning users could end up with a long delay before seeing the content, or that the server performance could grind to a crawl during peak usage.

Alternatively, you could host all your flash video content on YouTube and embed those videos, as the iPad has native support for (only) YouTube flash video. Or, you could display a message to the user stating that they must visit the page with a (third party) app that supports viewing flash videos, such as Skyfire.